# Citing (and correcting) an example with incorrect glossing and translation

Tags: citations, linguistics

I want to cite an example from a published paper. However, there is a mistake in the glossing as well as in the translation of the example. Imagine something like this (mistakes in bold):

*Ich sehe ihn.*
I see.**2SG** he.ACC
'**We** see him.' (SomeAuthor 2018: 1)

So, I know that [sic] or [*sic*] is used to indicate mistakes found in the original source. In this case, however, I'd rather just use a corrected version of the example - without citing the mistakes, as they are not relevant and could cause confusion.

Is there a common way to do this?

I was considering something like this:

*Ich sehe ihn.*
I see.1SG he.ACC
'I see him.' (SomeAuthor 2018: 1, corrected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mistakes are indeed as obvious as this (i.e., there cannot be a difference of interpretation), I would just use the corrected version and add a footnote to the citation in which you explain the differences.

If there could be a debate over which is the correct gloss or translation, list your own version but cite with something like "cf. SomeAuthor", and again add a footnote, this time with discussion as well.